# Finding a basis $C$ for which $[T]_C^C$ can be obtained non-computationally

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T$ is a linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that rotates vectors 30 degrees counterclockwise about the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

I need to first, come up with a basis $C$ that can be used to get $[T]_C^C$ without performing any computations, and second, find $[T]_C^C$.

I was thinking of using a basis such as $C=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$. Therefore, we could just rotate vectors about the "second" vector in the basis, effectively making the transformation matrix $[T]_C^C$ look like a rotation about the y-axis in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Am I on the right track with this? I just don't know if the first and third vectors matter and was also considering using $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in place of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ but I was thinking that it might not matter.

How would I then go about constructing $[T]_C^C$ in each case? Would any basis with $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in the second position yield the same result?

I'm thinking that using either of the bases I mentioned, $[T]_C^C$ would come out to something like $\begin{pmatrix} \cos{30} & 0 & -\sin{30} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sin{30} & 0 & \cos{30} \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} \cos{30} & 0 & \sin{30} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\sin{30} & 0 & \cos{30} \end{pmatrix}$, but I'm really not sure how to figure any of this out **without computations**. What am I missing?

Comment: It is best to take the two other vectors to be orthogonal to $(0, 1, 1)$, so it is better to choose $(0, -1, 1)$ instead of $(0, 0, 1)$.

Comment: Do you know how to figure out a matrix for rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ without many computations? A good basis to take in this case is two vectors at $30^\circ$ to each other, since you can easily draw right triangles with angles of $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$.

Comment: You could use this general formula for 3D rotation matrices: $$R = aa^T+\cos\theta(I_3-aa^T)+\sin\theta[a]_\times$$ where $a=[0,1,1]^T/\sqrt2$ , and $[a]_\times$ is the cross product matrix. The first term is projection onto the axis $a$. The second term is projection perpendicular to $a$, scaled by $\cos\theta$. The third term is projection perpendicular to $a$ and rotation by $90$ degrees around $a$, scaled by $\sin\theta$.

Comment: @mr_e_man I don't think this is the spirit of the question - after choosing a nice basis, the matrix in question should be really really easy to write down.